# using batch echo with special characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, echo

This maybe really easy but there were no answers for it over the net. I want to echo a XML line via batch into a file but it misunderstands the XML closing tag for redirection ">". The line is as follows:

```
echo <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> > myfile.xml
```

is there any way to give a hint to batch parser not to interpret a special string? I used double-quotes but it writes them to the file as well! The file should look like this after echo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch character escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can escape shell metacharacters with `^`:

```
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?^> > myfile.xml
```

Note that since `echo` is a shell built-in it doesn't follow the usual conventions regarding quoting, so just quoting the argument will output the quotes instead of removing them.

Comment: @Nevin: You still have to escape each and every `<` and `>`. Nothing special there. That being said, I'd advise against `echo`ing large XML files on a single line for ... kinda obvious reasons.

Comment: :Sorry to ask again..It's not working for me... Code is given below. Sorry for not giving the code in correct format

echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?^> ^<configuration^> ^<packageSources^> ^<add key="nuget.org" value="nuget.org/api/v2/"; /^> ^<add key="aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease" value="myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/"; /^> ^</packageSources^> ^</configuration^> >MyFile.xml –  Nevin Raj 1 hour ago

Comment: @Nevin: There are semicolons in there that should not be there. Apart from that it produces valid XML for me.

Comment: You were absolutely correct..The semicolon caused the trouble..Thanks

Comment: Not needing to batch very often, I keep forgetting my top 5 illegal `echo` characters: `<`, `>`,  `'`, `(` and `)`. All can be delimited with a caret `^`. More illegal characters [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) but most of them aren't in my typical use case.

Answer (score 34):

In order to use special characters, such as '>' on Windows with echo, you need to place a special escape character before it.

For instance

```
echo A->B
```

will not work since '>' has to be escaped by '^':

```
 echo A-^>B
```

See also [escape sequences](https://sites.google.com/site/opensourceconstriubtions/ettl-martin-1/tutorials/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-windows-batch-files-when-using-echo). 
[image]

There is a short batch file, which prints a basic set of special character and their escape sequences.

Comment: But for quotes, the caret is the escape character, using two quotes is wrong, as it adds simply a second quote. `echo Line1"" & echo line2` vs `echo Line1^" & echo line2`

Comment: Thanks for providing the table of examples.  It helped me with multiple characters.

Answer (score 23):

One easy solution is to use delayed expansion, as this doesn't change any special characters.

```
set "line=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  echo !line!
) > myfile.xml
```

**EDIT : Another solution is to use a *disappearing quote*.**

This technic uses a quotation mark to quote the special characters

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ""="
echo !"!<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

The trick works, as in the special characters phase the leading quotation mark in `!"!` will preserve the rest of the line (if there aren't other quotes).
And in the delayed expansion phase the `!"!` will replaced with the content of the variable `"` (a single quote is a legal name!).

If you are working with disabled delayed expansion, you could use a `FOR /F` loop instead.

`for /f %%^" in ("""") do echo(%%~" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

But as the seems to be a bit annoying you could also build a macro.

```
set "print=for /f %%^" in ("""") do echo(%%~""

%print%<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
%print% Special characters like &|<>^ works now without escaping
```

Comment: `echo !line!` will work as long as there are no `!` in the `line` variable. Any remedy for that?

Comment: No, if `line` contains a `!` then it will work without any problems, but it's not always obvious how to get the exclamation marks into the variable. Try `set "line=Hello^!" & echo !line!`

Comment: you are 100% correct. I must have looked over something!

Answer (score 23):

another method:

```
@echo off

for /f "useback delims=" %%_ in (%0) do (
  if "%%_"=="___ATAD___" set $=
  if defined $ echo(%%_
  if "%%_"=="___DATA___" set $=1
)
pause
goto :eof

___DATA___
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <root>
   <data id="1">
      hello world
   </data>
 </root>
___ATAD___


rem # 
rem #
```

Comment: Nice idea, to add data in a script!

Comment: Nice solution to unpack a text file from a batch file. The line `if defined $ echo(%%_` should be extended to `if defined $ echo(%%_ >> myxmlfile.xml` to copy the output into a file.

Comment: can we have variables inside ```__DATA__```?

Answer (score 11):

The way to output `>` character is to prepend it with `^` escape character:

```
echo ^>
```

will print simply

```
>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Joey was not working for me. 
After executing

```
  echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?^> > myfile.xml
```

I got this error
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

This solution worked for me:

```
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\">" > myfile.txt
```

See also http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: Note that this preserves the quotes in the output

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more approach by using `SET` and `FOR /F`

```
@echo off

set "var=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>"

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set var') do echo %%b
```

and you can beautify it like:

```
@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "print{[=for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set " & set "]}=') do echo %%b"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


set "xml_line.1=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>"
set "xml_line.2=<root>"
set "xml_line.3=</root>"

%print{[% xml_line %]}%
```

Answer (score -1):

the escape character `^` also did not work for me.
The single quotes worked for me (using ansible scripting)

```
shell: echo  '{{ jobid.content }}'
```

output:

```
 {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "echo  '<response status=\"success\" code=\"19\"><result><msg><line>query job enqueued with jobid 14447</line></msg><job>14447</job></result></response>'",
    "delta": "0:00:00.004943",
    "end": "2020-07-31 08:45:05.645672",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "echo  '<response status=\"success\" code=\"19\"><result><msg><line>query job enqueued with jobid 14447</line></msg><job>14447</job></result></response>'",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-07-31 08:45:05.640729",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "<response status=\"success\" code=\"19\"><result><msg><line>query job enqueued with jobid 14447</line></msg><job>14447</job></result></response>",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "<response status=\"success\" code=\"19\"><result><msg><line>query job enqueued with jobid 14447</line></msg><job>14447</job></result></response>"
    ]
```

Comment: the question is about batch/cmd. This surely won't work in batch/cmd.