# How to write an XML tag with double quotes using command prompt echo command

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, escaping, double-quotes

I would like to add the simpliest tag into a file, using a CMD batchfile, but it seems that the double quotes are spoiling the party:

From other StackOverflow posts I am aware of the double quote state machine and the usage of ^" (^ as an escape character). Still I can't make it work:
Hereby my attempts (with their results):

```
C:\>echo <tag variable="value">  // very naïve
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\>echo "<tag variable="value">"  // let's use quotes for delimiting the string
"<tag variable="value">"

C:\>echo "<tag variable=^"value^">" // let's use the escape character
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>echo "<tag variable=^"value^"> // what if the state machine is not switched back?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\>echo "<tag variable=^"value"> // desperate people do weird things :-)
"<tag variable=^"value">
```

I have also done some tests using the escape character in front of the tag characters < and > (as those have their own significance in CMD) but also there no good results.
Also first putting the entry within a variable (`set test="..."`) does not solve the issue.
As mentioned, I am getting desperate. The only thing I want to do is writing this into a text file:

```
<tag variable="value">
```

Can anybody help me out here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should replace "DOS" by "CMD" in your post (title and body)... I suppose you are not really working with DOS, are you?

Comment: @aschipfl: done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using batch echo with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308586/using-batch-echo-with-special-characters)

Comment: [Windows Batch System Info to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22029285/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the characters you want to escape are not the `"` but the `<`.
Then the correct syntax is this one :

```
C:\>echo ^<tag variable="value"^>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use the "\" char to escape a double quote ?
Like "echo "< tag blabla=\"value\" >" ?

EDIT

Seems like :

```
echo ^<tag variable=^"value^"^>
```

works fine !

Comment: Although your proposal is correct, the escaping of the double quotes is unnecessary, as mentioned by Mathiou.

Answer (score -1):

try with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "tag_line=<tag variable="value">"
echo !tag_line!
```