# How to escape characters in XML text when using Echo print to file

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to output the following line  to an xml file.

I am using the below command:

```
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" >> MyFile.xml
```

The only issue is that it is including the quotation marks at the begining and end in the file so inside of my file it looks like this:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"
```

Instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But if I try to run the batch file without the first and last quotes it fails and says `>> was unexpected at this time.`

So... those quotation marks are needed for it to work but it then prints those marks... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Given `cmd` and `batch-file` -- this is on Windows, right?

Comment: `echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"^>`

Comment: [Generating html with batch .. escape quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7942330/995714), [using batch echo with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7308586/995714), [Windows Batch System Info to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22029285/995714), [batch file write <> to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11407438/995714), [How to write an XML tag with double quotes using command prompt echo command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33015273/995714)

Comment: It would probably be better if you used a scripting language that has native support to reading and writing  XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using windows, so try this:

```
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?^> >> MyFile.xml
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is the correct answer and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to use [`delayed expansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "xml_line=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"
echo !xml_line!
:::
endlocal
```