# Windows Batch System Info to HTML

Tags: batch-file, operating-system, html, system-information

I am trying to create a batch file that will use the systeminfo command to put things such as the OS, domain currently logged onto, manufacture, computer model, etc. into an HTML table. This is the contents of my current batch file:

```
@echo off
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)"
pause
```

This is the current output:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Original Install Date:     7/26/2011, 1:47:23 AM
System Boot Time:          2/25/2014, 1:39:14 AM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Inspiron 1501
System Type:               X86-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I put this into a HTML table?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating html with batch .. escape quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942330/generating-html-with-batch-escape-quotes)

Comment: [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251557/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how fancy you want to get. The simplest way would be

```
@echo off
(
echo ^<HTML^> 
echo ^<BODY^> 
echo ^<pre^> 
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)"
echo ^</pre^> 
echo ^</BODY^> 
echo ^</HTML^>
)>sysinfo.html
```

And here is a way with a CSS formatted table

```
@echo off
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)">temp.txt
if exist systeminfo.html del /f /q systeminfo.html
call :CreateHTMLtable temp.txt systeminfo.html
if exist temp.txt del /f /q temp.txt
exit /b

:CreateHTMLTable <inputfile> <outputfile>
setlocal
>%2 echo ^<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
>>%2 echo "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
>>%2 echo  "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"^>
>>%2 echo ^<HTML^>
>>%2 echo ^<HEAD^>
>>%2 echo ^<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" 
>>%2 echo CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"^>
>>%2 echo ^</HEAD^>
>>%2 echo ^<BODY^>
>>%2 echo ^<style type="text/css"^>
>>%2 echo .tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #bcaf91;border-collapse: collapse;}
>>%2 echo .tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#ded0b0;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91;text-align:left;}
>>%2 echo .tftable tr {background-color:#e9dbbb;}
>>%2 echo .tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #bcaf91;}
>>%2 echo .tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
>>%2 echo ^</style^>
>>%2 echo ^<table class="tftable" border="1"^>
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (%1) do (
>>%2 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%a^</td^>^<td^>%%b^</td^>^</tr^>
)
>>%2 echo ^</table^>
>>%2 echo ^</BODY^>
>>%2 echo ^</HTML^>
```

Comment: How can I center the table, and also change the names in the left column (OS Version, etc.)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for you. Happy to provide any explanation.

```
@echo off
(
echo ^<table^>
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"OS Manufacturer" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"OS Build Type" /C:"Original Install Date" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"Processor(s)" /C:"BIOS Version" /C:"Windows Directory" /C:"System Directory" /C:"Boot Device" /C:"System Locale" /C:"Input Locale" /C:"Total Physical Memory" /C:"Available Physical Memory" /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size" /C:"Virtual Memory: Available" /C:"Virtual Memory: In Use" /C:"Domain" /C:"Network Card(s)">f.txt
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (f.txt) do echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%a^</td^> ^<td^>%%b^</td^>^</tr^>
echo ^</table^>
) >test.html
```

Obviously change the `>>test.html` to be the name of whatever file you want to output to, I suggest a variable might be best. You also might want to delete `f.txt` at the end of the script. You can style it by echoing whatever CSS to (I've used) `test.html`.

Comment: +1: But you don't need to redirect multiple times, enclose all in parenthesis and redirect only once: `(echo ^<table... for /f ... echo ^</table ) > test.htm`

Comment: @jeb haha, thank you, that would be more convenient. I will update my answer.