# Why does batch script crash without an error code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make an interface to make an split screen html file but there's a bug which doesn't return an error code

```
@echo off
color 1a
echo welcome to split screen creator - made by Tijmen
pause
cls
set /p file= type here the file name:
set /p links= left page:
set /p rechts= right page:
TimeOut 1 > nul
cls
echo generating
echo.>%file%.html <html><head><title>
echo.>%file%.html %file%
echo.>%file%.html </title></head>
echo.>%file%.html <frameset bordercolor="black" noresize
scrolling="auto" cols="%40, %40">
echo.>%file%.html <frame src="
echo.>%file%.html %links%
echo.>%file%.html ">
echo.>%file%.html <frame src="
echo.>%file%.html %rechts%
echo.>%file%.html ">
echo.>%file%.html </frameset>
echo.>%file%.html </html>
cls
echo ready
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape some of the characters you are writing to the file.

[Generating html with batch .. escape quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942330/generating-html-with-batch-escape-quotes)

For example, instead of this:

```
echo.>%file%.html <html><head><title>
echo.>%file%.html %file%
echo.>%file%.html </title></head>
echo.>%file%.html <frameset bordercolor="black" noresize
scrolling="auto" cols="%40, %40">
```

Try this:

```
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<title^> > %file%.html
echo %file% >> %file%.html
echo ^</title^>^</head^> >> %file%.html
echo ^<frameset bordercolor="black" noresize scrolling="auto" cols="%%40, %%40"^> >> %file%.html
```

Comment: I clicked the link in my answer and used the information there to generate a code sample for you.  If that works for you, please mark my answer as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `^` character is used to display or echo charcters (such as `<`, `>`) that are reserved for usage by cmd. So instead of `<html>`, `^<html^>` is used. Notice the `^` before the ampersand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JosefZ - the answer is fine (and correct), it was just formatted incorrectly.