# Select from another database table which have ] in her path

Tags: ms-access, path, escaping

With Access 2002, I fail to escape the ] character in a database path in a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=D:\bd].mdb;].[MYTABLE];
```

What I've tried and doesn't work :

```
SELECT * FROM ["MS Access;DATABASE=D:\bd].mdb;"].[MYTABLE];

SELECT * FROM [MS Access;"DATABASE=D:\bd].mdb";].[MYTABLE];
```

I didn't found anything in msdn documentation about escaping path : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194542.aspx

(I don't want to use link tables because the query is in fact to export data to excel or another db like SELECT * INTO [text;database=d:\;HDR=Yes].[csvfile.csv] FROM MyTable;)

Answer (score 0):

try this query..

```
SELECT [OtherAccessDB].* FROM [OtherAccessDB] IN 'D:\bd].mdb'
```

or if the ] isn't required...

```
SELECT [OtherAccessDB].* FROM [OtherAccessDB] IN 'D:\bd.mdb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't works with the special characters in path SELECT [MYTABLE].* FROM [MYTABLE] IN 'D:\bd].mdb'; => database engine cannot find 'D:\bd].mdb'

Comment: In a [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt), someone points out that Windows uses the caret as it's escape character.  Try `SELECT ... IN 'D:\db^].mdb'`  I don't have a virtual with Access handy, but you might try that.  @christiandev deserves the answer if that works.

Comment: @ErinsMatthew : Thanks, I tried but it seems that for access, ^ is treated as a regular character.