# git grep for less than or greater than character (in Windows shell)

Tags: git, cmd, escaping, windows-shell, msysgit

I'm trying to grep the word `<template>` in a git repository.

How do I write my `git grep` statement for this? (Shell seems to assume < and > as redirection  parameters)

(Looks like this is specific to [git for windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) run from a `cmd` session. Git Bash works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Git Bash, you should be able to simply quote it: `git grep "<template>"...`.

Running Git via Windows' `cmd.exe` is a little bit different. There, `git grep ^<template^> ...` should work. This is because `cmd.exe` uses `^` as its escape character (rather than `\`, which is used in Bash, ZSH, and just about every other shell out there).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt).

Comment: Note that this is how you handle any shell quoting, not just for `git`.

Comment: I'm running [git for windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) at the moment and doing a git grep "<template>" tells me `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: @Nocturne Are you using Git Bash or the Windows shell? If the latter, try `git grep "\<template\>"`. If the former, what this answer specifies should work as-is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Git Bash seems to work correctly. The problem seems to be with the Windows shell. `git grep "\<template\>"` fails with the error `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: ...yeah; a question about Windows Shell should probably be tagged as a cmd.exe question rather than anything about git; most folks who know git well, myself included, are more familiar with unixy platforms.

Comment: Yep, tagged correctly now. Didn't realize it was a Windows issue at the outset :)

Comment: Ah, I missed the Windows bit. Try `git grep ^<template^>` or `git grep "^<template^>"`. If it works I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Chris, yes, that does work :) Could you update your answer and explain what the caret does?