# How to output with ECHO into an HTML file tags with angle brackets without surrounding double quotes?

Tags: html, batch-file

I have written a batch file which creates an HTML file with ECHO command.

Example:

```
ECHO "<HTML><BODY><TABLE BORDER="1"><TR><TD> Copied WebFiles at %DATE% %TIME% </TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>" >> TEST.HTML
```

It's working perfectly, but ECHO command is also adding double quotes in HTML code.

How to avoid double quotes in HTML file?

Comment: HTML allows you to nest quote types. So you could have `BORDER='1'`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is with leaving out the double quotes as [Lekensteyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427545/lekensteyn) suggested already and additionally escape each angle bracket with `^` as explained at [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt).

```
ECHO ^<HTML^>^<BODY^>^<TABLE BORDER="1"^>^<TR^>^<TD^> Copied WebFiles at %DATE% %TIME% ^</TD^>^</TR^>^</TABLE^>^</BODY^>^</HTML^>>>TEST.HTML
```

There is also no space between `^</HTML^>` and `>>` as otherwise the space would be written also into the HTML file.

A space between `>>` and file name `TEST.HTML` is ignored and therefore you could insert here a space for better readability if your batch files are edited in a text editor without syntax highlighting for character `>`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution for your problem is change `ECHO` command by `SET /P`:

```
SET /P "=<HTML><BODY><TABLE BORDER="1"><TR><TD> Copied WebFiles at %DATE% %TIME% </TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>" >> TEST.HTML < NUL
ECHO/>> TEST.HTML
```