# batch to attribute ico inside folder as new icon

Tags: batch-file, directory, ico

I have a folder, and inside I have an .ico file that I want to set up as the icon to the main folder.

Here's my problem, if I do this manually and input this code

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0  
NoSharing=1  
IconFile=folder.ico
IconIndex=0
InfoTip=Some sensible information.
```

in a desktop.ini file it works great.

But if a create a bat file with the following code it does not.

```
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] >desktop.ini  
ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0 >>desktop.ini  
ECHO NoSharing=1 >>desktop.ini  
ECHO IconFile=folder.ico >>desktop.ini  
ECHO IconIndex=0 >>desktop.ini  
ECHO InfoTip=Some sensible information. >>desktop.ini
```

The Output is exactly the same. I also assigned the +r to the folder because without it it doesn't work either way.

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's due to several non-escaped special characters in your commands. If you run the batch first, then open `desktop.ini` to see its content, you'll find it's far from your expectation.

Problems:

1. Excessive blank space at the end of each line.

   A  appears on the left of `>`, which means an extra blank space to be added to the file.

   To solve this, simply remove this space. Like `ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0>>desktop.ini`.
2. Un-escaped numbers

   `ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0>>desktop.ini` means write `ConfirmFileOp=` to the command window and pipe stdout to `desktop.ini`. `0` is a piping token.

   To solve this, escape the numbers by `^0`, `^1` or so. Reference - [Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251557/3839249)

   An easier way is by writing output redirecting instruction at the beginning of the line  -

   ```
   >>desktop.ini echo ConfirmFileOp=0
   ```
3. Improper file attributes

   `desktop.ini` should be hidden, system, and NOT archived. Reference - https://superuser.com/a/396051/333430
   You can [change the attributes](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) of `desktop.ini` by adding the following line to the batch script:

   ```
   attrib desktop.ini -a +h +s
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the response Yvon, but that didn't solve it.

I know desktop.ini its a hidden file.

The curious thing is, if I imput the same code to a txt file and then convert that file using another bat file with the following 
    
    ren *.txt *.ini

It works and the icon shows up.

But If I put that same code in the end of the previous code It doesn´t work, that's awkward.

Comment: @JoãoLagoas did you log off and log in again after this process?

Comment: @JoãoLagoas It also happens to me that, when I first created such a file in a new folder, nothing happened; when I first changed the icon in "properties" (of another new folder), any following operations (enable icon, disable icon, change icon, etc. ) worked. I'm not sure why this occurs, but Windows seems to be immune to auto-generated desktop.ini, in case of malware or virus. User input such as writing .txt file will create the file with explorer.exe in the first place; this may be the difference.