# Replacing angle brackets in variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a plain text file with one url per line, enclosed with <link></link> tags. ECHO-ing the variablee (including the tags) works fine but now I'd like to remove the tags. [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt) the angle brackets with one or multiple ^ does not work.
here's the code

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr "<link>" test.txt`) DO (
SET what=%%F
SET result=%what:<link>=%
ECHO %result%
)
```

is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and quotes when you are using > or <:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr "<link>" test.txt`) DO (
    SET "what=%%F"
    SET "result=!what:<link>=!"
    ECHO !result!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: @JosefZ: Not the case. Reaching EOF is equivalent to an `endlocal`.

Comment: Not the case. You need delayed expansion here because the variables in use are within a block. The quotes serve only to ensure trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.

Comment: @Magoo yes, but I do not see an `EOF`, I don't see whether or not the OP's code snippet is embedded in some outer loop etc... Let's go to _meta_  with it...

Comment: @JosefZ: Did you removed some comments here? Please, _don't_! Remember that this is a public forum and any other user that read these comments (like me) will have not idea of what you and Magoo are talking about... `:(`

Comment: @Aacini Sorry, I did not remove anything; see [my edit Summary](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28120693/revisions). It states literally: _'setlocal' should be always coupled with corresponding 'endlocal' as a kind of parentheses_