# Passing the greater than character '>' as command line argument to a Python script

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a Python script that needs to accept the "greater than" character `>` as a command-line argument.

```
python myscript.py -f "VALUE>100"
```

However, even if I wrap that argument in double-quotes, python is still parsing that character as a redirect operator. I checked it through the Python debugger in VS Code and it shows that the `>` character and succeeding characters are not included in `argv`.

[image: argv in VSCode python debugger]

Is there a workaround for this?
My OS is Windows and I'm using cmd.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: cmd. I'm in Windows

Comment: This is a question about `cmd`, not a question about Python, then. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt) by putting `windows cmd escape greater-than` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+cmd+escape+greater-than), as the second result. Did you try anything similar?

Comment: The ^ escape character worked! Thanks! The weird thing though is that wrapping it in double-quotes works for my other command-line tools but not with Python.