# How to use angle brakets ("<") in curl post?

Tags: curl, post

I'm trying to send curl POST like this. (It's for Slack Webhook)

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"username\": \"name\", \"text\": \"Some alert! <https://some.alert.url/|Click Here.>\"}" https://some.channel.url
```

It Says

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Including "<", "|" throws this error.
Tried setting variable, "\<", and so on...

How could I send this url properly?

tried replacing " to '
[image: tried replacing " to ']

tried putting \ before <, >
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.

I'm running this on Windows cmd. So I should not use "" but "^" for the escape character.

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"username\": \"name\", \"text\": \"Some alert! ^<https://some.alert.url/|Click Here.^>\"}" https://some.channel.url
```

This works fine.

[Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt)