How do you escape the redirection (<<) character in a JSON string contained in a cURL command?
I have a HTTP CRUD API that I am able to successfully send commands to. I'm using cURL from the command prompt on Windows 11.
However, when I send the redirection character, "<<", as part of a JSON string, I get an error.
Example cURL command:
curl -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"id\": \"b6481929-ec66\", \"dialogue\": \"<b> <<winks>>You are kewl </b>\"}" https://myfakeurl.xyz/items

The error:
<< was unexpected at this time.

Does anyone know how I can successfully escape the redirection characters (<<) in my JSON string within the cURL command?
I have tried using the Windows escape character ^ in the manner referenced in
Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt
Update:
Using the ^ characters, here is modified JSON portion of the cURL command I entered:
 "{\"id\": \"b6481929-ec66\", \"dialogue\": \"^<^ b> ^<^<winks^>^> You are kewl ^<^/b>\"}"

And the error I received:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I have also tried the following variations on the << portion of the JSON string:
^<^<^winks^>^>

^<^^<^winks^>^>

I'm running Windows 11 Pro. The build version is 10.0.22631.3737.

This question is similar to: Escape angle brackets in a Windows command prompt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

^<^ ^>^> works for me on Win10; what exactly happened when you 'tried' it? In addition to PowerShell (where curl is actually an alias for invoke-webrequest so use curl.exe for the real program), an alternative way to avoid quoting hell is to put your data in a file, without the outer quotes or any backslashes OR hats, and use curl[.exe] ... -d @filename

@dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the attention. I'm still not having success. Will you please post the full string you used?

See answer(?). In ^<^ b> and ^<^/b> you didn't put the second hats in the right place which is immediately before the > (and also added a space that doesn't belong)

This is a trivial answer and I agree to deletion if appropriate (e.g. to close as typo)
c:\temp>curl -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"id\": \"b6481929-ec66\", \"dialogue\": \"^<b^> ^<^<winks^>^>You are kewl ^</b^>\"}" https://httpbin.org/anything/anything
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"id\": \"b6481929-ec66\", \"dialogue\": \"<b> <<winks>>You are kewl </b>\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "69",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/8.7.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6684ef46-37d0b89965dd85fa60a3bed9"
  },
  "json": {
    "dialogue": "<b> <<winks>>You are kewl </b>",
    "id": "b6481929-ec66"
  },
  "method": "PUT",
  "origin": "REDACTED",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything/anything"
}

c:\temp>


Now that I see your solution and compare it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251557/escape-angle-brackets-in-a-windows-command-prompt, I would agree to deletion as well. Thank you again!

Close vote submitted.
